# How to find anchor link within anchor tag and click on that link automatically using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to find anchor link within anchor tag and click on that link automatically in jquery.

example

```
<div id="myid">
<a id="interestingness" href="htttp://mylink.com">mytestinglink</a>
</div>
```

Comment: On all HTML5 compliant browsers, you can just use: `interestingness.click();`

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
$('#interestingness')[0].click();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="myid">
<a id="interestingness" href="htttp://mylink.com" target="_blank">mytestinglink</a>
</div>
```

```
$("#interestingness").click(function(){
          var currentAnchor = $(this);
          alert(currentAnchor.text());
          alert(currentAnchor.attr('href'));
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

`$('#interestingness').click();`